# How to fix the error object could be possibly undefined using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

while using a variable within condition i get the error object could be possibly undefined.

Below is the snippet,

```
render = () => {
    const value_to_check = 8 //got by some http request could be any number
    return (
        <>
        {condition1 && condition2 && (
            value_to_check < 1 ? null : ( //here is where i get the pycharm 
            //error object could be undefined
            <div1>something</div1>
        ))}
    )
}
```

How could i fix that error. thanks.

Comment: Export it in a function and use normal condition

Comment: thanks but i dint get it..could you show it with an example

Comment: @someuser2491 can you share the value_to_check logic? maybe converting the value to a number might work but it's hard to tell

Comment: So the object could be possibly undefined is the ``value_to_check`` which as you commented on the code got by some http request and could be anything?

Comment: @FaristaLatuconsina : yes value_to_check

Comment: also to note the value within value_to_check will always be number just that could be undefined, 0 or anything above that.

Comment: Your IDE won't know it will always be number, string, or what else. That's why it gives you error there. Except u give it default value. another reason, what if your request failed ? the value_to_check will be undefined. what if the response changes ? You won't know when this happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
render = () => {
    const value_to_check = 8 //got by some http request could be anything
    
    return (
        <>
        {condition1 && condition2 && (
            // value_to_check might be undefined and u still compare it with < 1.
            value_to_check < 1 ? null : ( //here is where i get the pycharm 
            //error object could be undefined
            <div1>something</div1>
        ))}
        
        // Solution ( Notes: I don't recommend the style below, it's hard to read)
        {condition1 && condition2 && value_to_check && ( value_to_check < 1 ? null : <div>Something</div>)}
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```