# How to fix the object is probably undefined error within a reusable component using react and typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting error object is possibly undefined when i use the variable "items_count".

what i am trying to do?
I have an ContainerComponent that uses ContentComponent which displays an icon. This ContentComponent is a reusable component.

Below is my ContainerComponent

```
render = () => {
    const items_count = 10; //got by http request and its value could be undefined, 0 or anything 
    //above 0
    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <LeftSide>
                <ContainerComponent>
                    <ContentComponent>
                        items_count=10
                        icon_name='add'
                    </ContentComponent>
               </ContainerComponent>
           </LeftSide>
           <RightSide>
               <ContainerComponent>
                   <ContentComponent>
                       icon_name='delete'
                   </ContentComponent>
               </ContainerComponent>
           </RightSide>
       </Wrapper>
   )
```

}

ContentComponent renders the Icon and it looks like below,

```
const ContentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
    icon_name,
    items_count,
}) => {
    return (
        {condition1 && condition2 &&
            (icon_name === 'add' && items_count < 1 ? null : ( //here i get error object items_count 
            //could be possibly undefined
                <firstdiv>
                   <seconddiv>
                       <Icon name={icon_name} />
                   </seconddiv>
                </firstdiv>
            ))}
    )
}
```

To fix the error i have tried something like below

```
return (
    {condition1 && condition2 && items_count && //added a check here
        (icon_name === 'add' && items_count < 1 ? null : (
            <firstdiv>
                <seconddiv>
                    <Icon name={icon_name} />
                </seconddiv>
            </firstdiv>
     ))}
)
```

But as you see in the ContainerComponent RightSide component i dont pass the items_count and within ContentsComponent i want this icon with name delete to render always irrespective of items_count value. and icon with name add to render only when items_count value is greater than 0.

that check in my snippet works but gives error item_count could be possibly undefined. how can i fix it..could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: I think i have answered your question before, this is your thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61744846/how-to-fix-the-error-object-could-be-possibly-undefined-using-react-and-typescri/61745376#61745376

Comment: yes true. but that din work in this case. i posted that question earlier without the parent component like in this question. where one of the child components doesnt have the items_count passed at all.

Comment: So delete will always show, but `add` only show if items_count > 0 ?

Comment: yes you got it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will always show the `delete` icon, and sometimes the `add` icon will show side by side with the delete icon

```js
/* U just need to change the structure of your code
*/
const ContentComponent: React.FC<Props> = ({
    icon_name,
    items_count,
}) => {
    const renderIcon = () => {
      if(!condition1 || !condition2 || !items_count) return null
      return (
        <firstdiv>
           <seconddiv>
               <Icon name='delete'} />
               {items_count > 0 ? <Icon name='add'} /> : null }
           </seconddiv>
        </firstdiv>
      )
    }

    return (
      <>
        {renderIcon()}
      </>
    )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks a lot..but this condition1 and condition2 stil applies to icon with delete...i am trying to refactor the code as much as possible.

Comment: No, it's independent. Only `add` icon have condition1 and condition2

Comment: hmm no...delete and add icons are dependant on condition 1 and condition 2. and independant of items_count.

Comment: Who depends on items_count ?

Comment: only the icon named add